# eevee volumetric light visible through objects

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have a problem, or rather found a limitation in eevee that when an object is too close to a light, volumetrics will show in front of the object, like here

[image]

I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me where is a setting (because there must be one!) to control in what minimal distance do volumetrics clip through other objects.

That said the object in the screenshot is solidified - there is room for the spotlight like so:

[image]

in material settings everything is set to opaque and I have tried everything that came obvious to me like checking normals.

Comment: Render tab > Volumetrics, try decreasing the End value a whole bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix, go to *Render Properties > Volumetrics* and increase samples to `128` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

For the render view, you have to play around with *Start* and *End* distance of volumetrics depending on the distance of representation and on the distance your camera is positioned. It's gonna be different for every case.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other methods worked for me. What I did was I increased the radius of the spot light.

It will dim the light. Then I increased the power to compensate for it.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that increasing the samples does not always work. We fixed this by removing "Volumetric Lighting" from the volumetrics settings (I had the same problem on another project).